# Adding an asp.net MVC page along with Azure Mobile services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have backend(e.g. https://api.myapp.com) based on the Azure Mobile services(AMS), now I need
1. add one or two apis that doesn't require to be on AMS e.g. an heartbeat controller to check that service is online or not, that doesn't require Zumo Auth
2. an ASP.net MVC page(e.g. https://www.myapp.com) that explains about the application

Can I use the existing AMS to do this, I tried to add plain asp.net web api, but getting error that end point doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you truly using Azure Mobile Services and not Azure Mobile Apps?  You generally cannot have a custom domain on Azure Mobile Services.  Since you mention ZUMO Auth 2, I'm assuming you mean App Service Auth and thus Azure Mobile Apps.

I'd recommend taking a look at Azure Functions for any APIs that do not require ZUMO.  However, you can just add a custom API to your service.  I cover all the options for you in my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 4.

As to a service controller for checking heartbeat.  If the intent is to ensure that the service is alive, then just create an unauthenticated custom API that tests the database connectivity (maybe does an SQL command to get the count of rows in your main table) and returns success or failure.  You can then use Azure Functions, Azure Scheduler or OMS to do a query of that custom API.

Comment: Sorry for confusion caused, I am using Azure mobile Apps. Azure function app is going to hosted at the separate end point. I want the endpoint to be same, there would be several in memory data structures that needs to be accessed in the same app, so azure function will not work, Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In that case, use a custom API within your Mobile App.

Comment: I added a custom api, as simple as VS2015, add Web API 2 controller with R/W action. and call this as http://localhost:xyz/api/test gives me a 404. When I add attribute [MobileAppController] on my controller class, then calling this api requires X-Zumo-auth. Do we have any other alternative.

Comment: You shouldn't require X-ZUMO-AUTH header unless you add [Authorize] or unless you have the App Service Authentication set to always require authentication.  This is a separate problem, so please open a separate question if this doesn't assist.

Comment: My bad, I mean it requires ZUMO-API-VERSION header

Comment: Yes - just leave off the [MobileAppController] and route it like a normal WebAPI.  See the book - http://aka.ms/zumobook - chapter 4 contains a lot of examples of what you can do.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, will try that in our next version, we just launched our app for windows http://www.rebusly.com

Comment: Adrian, Thanks, I think I was missing the             config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); at Startup, adding this fixed the issue